# How to start Travis CI deploy only when tag name matches a regex

Tags: regex, bash, travis-ci

I want to kick off an npm deployment when a tag, that looks like a semantic version, is pushed, e.g. `v1.2.3`. I see that the tag name is in the `TRAVIS_TAG` environment variable and that I can specify an `on:` condition, which "can be any Bash condition". I have no idea what to write here and how to debug it.

`- provider: npm
  on:
    tags: true
    all_branches: true
    condition: ???`

Ideally, I would like to not bother with Bash at all - I would like the condition to execute a Node.js script and then decide whether to deploy or not depending on the node exit code. How can I do that?

Answer (score 21):

Simplest way would still be with bash, this example will deploy only if tag name matches the regex "release.*":

```
on:
    tags: true
    all_branches: true
    condition: "$TRAVIS_TAG =~ ^release.*$"
```

Check out this link for more info on travis environment variables:
http://docs.travis-ci.com/user/ci-environment/#Environment-variables

Comment: Ho-hum, can you give me an example of writing a condition that delegates to a `node` script?

Comment: This throws an error "[x] syntax error: (<unknown>): found unknown escape character while parsing a quoted scalar at line .... ".

Comment: Double quote is giving the problem "unknown escape character". Remove double quotes and it should work.

Comment: @eshirazi How to test these changes are working with travis without pushing a tag?

Answer (score 6):

eshizari's answer didn't work for me. This is the approach that I'm using instead:

```
on:
  all_branches: true
  condition: $TRAVIS_TAG =~ ^v[0-9]+\.[0-9]+\.[0-9]+
```