# trigger travis CI build only with specific commit message

Tags: github, travis-ci

I want travis to start only if I have a certian commit message.
how can i do this. My travis.yml file is [here](https://github.com/mosaadm/mooltipass/blob/master/.travis.yml)

I know there is an on condition from this [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24679889/how-to-start-travis-ci-deploy-only-when-tag-name-matches-a-regex) but I dont know where to put it.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24679889/how-to-start-travis-ci-deploy-only-when-tag-name-matches-a-regex) you mentioned regards deploying travis build. So `on:` condition only determines if build is deployed or not. Regardless this setting other build steps are executed on each commit/pull request.

What you could use instead is adding `[ci skip]` or `[skip ci]` in commit messages to force [build skipping](https://docs.travis-ci.com/user/customizing-the-build/#Skipping-a-build).

You can also use `TRAVIS_COMMIT_MESSAGE` [default env variable](https://docs.travis-ci.com/user/environment-variables/#Default-Environment-Variables) in all your [build steps](https://docs.travis-ci.com/user/customizing-the-build/#The-Build-Lifecycle) to determine if step should be executed or skipped, e.g.

```
 script: if [[ $TRAVIS_COMMIT_MESSAGE == *"trigger build"* ]]; then mvn install ; fi ;
```