# Skipping a script in travis based on commit message

Tags: continuous-integration, travis-ci

I want to control some of my travis scripts with a commit message.
Like for example travis gives this command for commit messages 
`my commit [skip travis]` which essentially skips a travis build.

What I want is not to skip travis entirely, as we use it to deploy our app, but only to not run some scripts which we can enforce via a commit message.

Can anyone help me out here?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use the default env variable `TRAVIS_COMMIT_MESSAGE` to check for your desired commit message.
For eg:- You can use the code snippet I have taken from [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/44907073/5893995).

```
script: if [[ $TRAVIS_COMMIT_MESSAGE == *"urgent fix"* ]]; then npm install ; fi ;
```

**P.S.** You can check the default env variables [here](https://docs.travis-ci.com/user/environment-variables/#default-environment-variables)