# How to deploy based on some condition in travis?

Tags: configuration, yaml, travis-ci

Currently, I have the travis deploy configuration like this:

```
deploy:
  on:
    tags: true
```

But I want to add the deploy based on some condition something like this

```
if branch=='something'
deploy:
  on:
    tags: true
```

Is it possible to do something like the above?

Comment: See https://docs.travis-ci.com/user/deployment-v2/conditional

Answer (score 1):

```
on:
    tags: true
    condition: "$TRAVIS_TAG =~ ^\d+\.\d+\.\d+$"
```

Reference [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24679889/how-to-start-travis-ci-deploy-only-when-tag-name-matches-a-regex).